# How can I export gallery images from SquareSpace?

Tags: image, download, export, gallery, squarespace

SquareSpace does not offer any way to export uploaded content directly. The only export option available is for WordPress, but this only generates a small XML file. What is the best way to download the actual image files from a gallery, other than right-clicking each image and choosing "Save as..."?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me [Python]. If you take the XML file that is exported for you, you can run the following against it.

I had only .png images uploaded. You will have to modify to include jpg and other image file formats.

```py
    import requests
    import shutil
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    tree = ET.parse('filename.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    for i in root.findall('wp:attachment_url'):
        print(i)

    images = set([elem.text for elem in root.iter() if elem.tag=='link' and '.png' in elem.text])

    for img in images:
        resp = requests.get(img+'?format=3000w', stream=True)
        local_file = open(f'images/{img.split("/")[-1]}', 'wb')
        resp.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(resp.raw, local_file)
        del resp
```

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome: File > Save Page As > Web Page Complete

Do this for each page that you want to download the images from.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent way too long figuring out how to do this, so I'm leaving this here in hopes that it will save someone else time. It's not pretty, and it involves a browser extension, but I believe this is the most efficient way. Broadly speaking, this is what the process looks like:

1. Set up new local WordPress installation. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-local-wordpress-site-using-xampp/
2. Export your SquareSpace site for WordPress and import it into the new installation. Ignore errors about attachments. All image galleries will now show up as pages in WordPress, with each image hotlinked to the medium-sized version of the image in the original SquareSpace site. https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206566687-Exporting-your-site
3. Install a browser extension that lets you bulk-download images on a webpage. I used this Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bulk-image-downloader/lamfengpphafgjdgacmmnpakdphmjlji

Repeat the following steps for each gallery:

3. On the page editor, switch to text view. Copy the HTML into your favorite text editor, and use the find/replace feature to replace ".JPG" with ".JPG?format=2500w" on every image URL to force the full-size resolution. Paste the updated HTML back into WordPress and update the page.
4. View the updated page, and use the browser extension you installed earlier to download all the images on the page. If you have a large gallery, you might have to scroll down to the bottom of the page to force all the images to load before downloading them.

That's it. All said and done, it's a pretty simple and straightforward process. I went through a lot of different WordPress plugins in an attempt to rehost the external links to the local wp-content folder, export the media library by post, etc. This ended up being much faster and much simpler. Hope it saves you some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many images, you can do them one at a time from a gallery.  While viewing a gallery (Chrome) I can right-click and open the image in a new tab and then save that (getting rid of the parameters after *.jpeg )

Answer (score 0):

You can use this repo to download the images from Squarespace. It has a Tkinter GUI to make it easier to use :)

I just coded it and it works fine on my end.

Github link: https://github.com/Mascobot/squarespace_image_downloader

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Image Downloader plugin from Chrome. Super easy to download all images into folders. Once installed, go to the URL of your website page, hit the plugin, and create a download folder. Done.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternative:

Use a crawler like ScreamingFrog and crawl your entire domain.
Copy all of your image URLs.

Download the Chrome Addon 'Tab Save' and paste all the links in there.

Download them. Done!

Answer (score -2):

Copy the image and open it in a photo editor like Preview and then export it.
That works well for a few images but not so well for many. 
Or screen shots. Make the image as large as possible and screen shoot it that way.

Comment: This is not a "gallery" download of files.